# Exporting SSRS Report to a .CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, number-formatting

I have a data filed for invoices that have multiple invoice numbers separated by a comma example (1711168,1711173,1711175) when I go to save as a .csv file the results look like this: 171116817111731000000. How can I keep the format using expressions

Comment: SSRS, by default, adds a text qualifier (`"`) when a text string contains a delimiter (`,`). Is the textbox set to a number display format, rather than text?

Comment: Change it to text (`@`).  A delimited list of numbers is not a number.

Comment: I am sort of new at this how do I change it to text(@)!

Comment: In the same place you just checked it's display format.

Comment: That is not working for me I still have the same results when I export to .csv file

Comment: When you open the file in notepad, are there quotes around the field (or any others)?

Comment: yes only that field and my comments field!

Comment: I figured it out i used pipe delimiter Chr(10) to my expression: =Fields!InvoiceNumber.Value & Chr(10)